# Integrate jquery masked input as angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wish to use [masking](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) in form inputs. I have created a directive `uiMask` which takes predefined masking formats like `DoB` or `zip`. In order to initiate masking, I apply the masking in directive's `link` function. And to update the model I manually trigger the digest cycle using `$apply` on `keyup`. Is this approach correct?

```js
angular.module('formApp', [])
.controller("DemoFormController",['$scope',function($scope){
 
}])
.directive('uiMask', [
  function () {
    return {
      require:'ngModel',
      scope: {
       type : "@uiMask"
      },
      controller: function($scope){
       $scope.dob = "99/99/9999";
       $scope.zip = "99999";
      },
      link:function ($scope, element, attrs, controller) {

       var $element = $(element[0]);
       $element.mask($scope.$eval($scope.type));
        /* Add a parser that extracts the masked value into the model but only if the mask is valid
         */
        controller.$parsers.push(function (value) {
          var isValid = value.length && value.indexOf("_") == -1;
          return isValid ? value : undefined;
        });
        /* When keyup, update the view value
         */
        element.bind('keyup', function () {
          $scope.$apply(function () {
            controller.$setViewValue(element.val());
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="formApp">
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.3.1/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="DemoFormController" class="container">
    {{employee | json}}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dob" name="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth" ui-mask="dob" ng-model="employee.dob">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="Zip" ui-mask="zip" ng-model="employee.zip" >
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with putting a jQuery "plugin" (uniform.js) into an angular directive. I think what might help is if you attached a `$watch` to the element. Here is what I did for the uniform directive:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

    angular.module('pfmApp').directive('uniform', function($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                $(element).addClass('uniform').uniform();
                //$(element).uniform.update();
                scope.$watch(function() { return ngModel.$modelValue }, function() {
                    $timeout(jQuery.uniform.update, 0);
                });
            }
        }
    });

}());
```

I hope this helps or perhaps points you in the right direction.